# Google App Engine - Document Editor Creation/Tap Into Google Docs?

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine, tinymce, text-editor

What is the best way to create a custom document editor in GAE? I'm making a website meant for a School Robotics Club (With support for any other organization - DRY).

We currently use Google services for online collaboration, I'm wondering if there is a way to tap into Google Docs and allow users to edit a Google Document *without* using Google Accounts or the Google Docs [EDIT]<s>interface</s> website[/EDIT].

If that is not possible (I've researched and I don't think it is), what is the best way to make a document editor? I want it completely on the website I'm creating, so I'm assuming just some javascript editor like TinyMCE + Ajax + Datastore. Is their anything that replicates Google Doc's/Microsoft Offices's/OpenOffice.org's feature set as far as fonts, spacing, alignment, justification, etc.?

Comment: Why the prohibition on Google accounts, or on the docs interface?

Comment: Let me clarify: I don't want to send my users to the http://docs.google.com/ domain, like a separate site. A link to the document itself might work...

EDIT: And Google Accounts might be acceptable if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by 'use' - if you don't want Google Accounts, or the editor, it's hard to see what's left. You can use the [document list data API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/overview.html) to upload, download, and convert docs.

Comment: The editor would work fine. I just don't want to make my users need to sign up for a separate account in addition to my website's. If it's necessary I could just use Google Accounts for the entire site. However I'd still like the documents to be "owned" by the site... eg: I don't want to do something that might as well be done through the Google Document's site separately. The user would need to see documents for their "Organization." Could Google Apps tie into this?

Comment: Using Google Accounts for your site seems like a good idea. No, you can't allow people to edit documents they don't have access to, but you can use the API to add and revoke permission to docs as you wish. Again, though, why complicate things? Why not use what's already there?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you want to use the Google Docs editor like a widget within your application.  To the best of my knowledge you can't do this.